# The momentum of particle will increase or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, photons, momentum, collision

If a particle is moving having specific momentum, and the particle is hit with photons continuously. Will the momentum of that particle increase or not (by adding momentum)?

Comment: The process is known as the Compton effect : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the photon can give momentum to the particle. However, at the scale of a single photon, you would have to take into account quantum effects. Even if you have a direct head-on collision between a photon and a particle, there's no guarantee what exactly would happen. The photon could end up passing right through the particle as if it weren't there (in which case, there would be no momentum transfer). It could also "bounce" off the particle at various angles, in which case the momentum of the particle would change.

Now, if we're talking about a bunch of photons bouncing off of a large mirror suspended in space, then those photons will also give momentum to the mirror. This is the principle behind [solar sails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail), for example.

**Edit**:
If the energy of the collision is high enough, additional particles may be produced by the collision. For example, a photon and an electron could collide and produce an additional electron and a positron.

Comment: Suppose collision increase the momentum of particle. In such case  photon will increase the mass of that particle or the velocity of that particle?

Comment: The mass of a free particle is a property of that particle and does not change. However, additional particles may be created if the energy is high enough.

Comment: It increases its kinetic enegy $T = p^2 / 2m$

Answer (score 2):

Photons are elementary particles described in the standard model of physics and their interaction with other particles is described by specific quantum mechanical interactions.

In this framework one does not "hit a particle with photons" one has *photon particle interactions*  and the momentum of the particle can change in various ways, and the probability of scattering and the momenta distributions  are  calculable in quantum electrodynamics.

If the photon energy is too low for particle production,  if the scattering is elastic only the direction of the particle changes, if inelastic the energy and momentum of the particle increases, the photon departing with smaller energy/momentum. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering). Consecutive interactions will follow the same rules.

Comment: Because total momentum and total energy always conserved, the particle absorbs an amount of that photon's energy.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about elastic collision (no energy loss), it would depend on the angle between the photon velocity vector and particle velocity vector. For simplicity. If you just have one dimension, let it be the x dimension, and the particle is moving in the +ve x direction, and a photon, which has the same direction, collided with it, definitely the particle momentum will increase and the new photon generated will be in the -ve x direction and it will have less frequency. If the reverse happened and the photon was coming in the -ve x direction, the particle momentum  will decrease and the photon frequency will increase.

The above analysis can be obtained and generalized from the generalization of Compton scattering

Comment: Suppose collision increase the momentum of particle. In such case  photon will increase the mass of that particle or the velocity of that particle?